# Datatable not showing the data but table is filled with data using json object

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am filling the table using json object and using table add row method. Some time it do not show any data but data is in object and also added in the table. When i just click on the next page or any table page its starts showing the data.
[DataTable screen with issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnmum.png)

Table initialization.

```
var oRenewalsTable = $('#RenewalsTable').DataTable({
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-6'B><'col-sm-3'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
            "autoWidth": false,
            responsive: true,
            columnDefs: [
                { orderable: false, targets: [0, 8, 9] },
                { width: "1%", targets: 0 },
                { width: "7%", targets: 9 },
                { className: "dt-center", targets: [0,4,5,6,7,8,9] }
            ],
            order: [[1, 'asc']],
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Validate',
                    className: 'btn-primary',
                    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                        ValidateAllChecked();
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Confirm',
                    className: 'btn-success',
                    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                        ConfirmAllChecked();
                    }
                },
                'copy',
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    title: 'Excel Contract Renewal List',
                    footer: false,
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    title: 'PDF Contract Renewal List ',
                    footer: false,
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                    }
                }, 'colvis'
            ]
        });
```

Add data to table using json object.

```
oRenewalsTable.row.add([
                        checkbox,
                        response[i].Company,
                        response[i].Vehicle,
                        response[i].Serial,
                        response[i].SIMCode,
                        response[i].InstallationDate,
                        response[i].Status,
                        renewalDate,
                        Online,
                        confirmButton + editButton
                    ]).draw(false);
```

This method used to clear the table.

```
    var ClearDataTable = function (tableVar) {
    tableVar.clear();
    tableVar.draw();
    };
```

I need to maintain the table pagination state but if i do not maintain table state it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much pain at last I found the answer, posting here just if anyone else get the same problem. According to [datatable documentation for clear()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()#Example):

If you want to save the pagination state while reloading the data to datatable then first clear the table and and redraw the table using false as a parameter.

```
oRenewalsTable.clear();
oRenewalsTable.draw(false);
```

If you do not want to save the pagination state while reloading the data to datatable then just clear and redraw the table.

```
oRenewalsTable.clear();
oRenewalsTable.draw();
```

and to gain morer performance just use:

```
oRenewalsTable.clear().draw(false);    
oRenewalsTable.clear().draw();
```